# MATLAB: loop through many files and give new files unique names

Tags: matlab, csv

I need matlab to read through a directory of similarly named csv files e.g. `/path/to/matrix1.csv`, `/path/to/matrix2.csv`, etc, and to output `newmatrix1.csv`, `newmatrix2.csv`, etc. This is my code:

```
files=dir('all_zrmat/*.csv')
for filenum = 1:length(files)
    csv=csvread(files(filenum).name)
    ROI=[7 8 9 10 28 29 71 72 73 74]
    Whole=files(filenum).name
    rwd_net=ones(10,10)
    rwd_net=rwd_net*3
    for i = 1:10
        rwd_net(i,1:4)=Whole(ROI(i),7:10)
        rwd_net(i,5:6)=Whole(ROI(i),28:29)
        rwd_net(i,7:10)=Whole(ROI(i),71:74)
    end
    outfile=['rwdnet_' files(filenum).name]
    csvwrite('outfile',rwd_net)
end
```

I tried just line by line to make sure it works, and this line...

```
>> outfile = ['rwdnet_' files(filenum).name]
```

...gives me this crazy long string.

```
rwdnet_zr_matrix.csvzr_matrix000T.csvzr_matrix001T.csvzr_matrix003.csv...
```

Those labels are correct, but I'm not sure if that's what it's naming the output files, or what? I'm pretty new to MATLAB, so there's probably other mistakes. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers.

(I have the `rwd_net=rwd_net*3` just to show me that the script is correctly outputting values.)

Answer (score 0):

Change `csvwrite('outfile', rwd_net);` to `csvwrite(outfile, rwd_net);`.  Remove the quotations around `outfile`.  You want to use the string contained in `outfile` as the filename.  Placing `outfile` in quotes means that you are naming the file as `outfile`, and not the intended filename you want... so at each iteration in your loop, you are overwriting the file.

Comment: Ah good point, thanks! But I'm still not sure how to correctly define `outfile`, because `outfile=['rwdnet_' files(filenum).name]` isn't doing what I want it to

Comment: @uncommon_currency - Are you sure?  It looks like `outfile` is correctly creating the string.  It shouldn't concatenate.  Do this after you create `outfile` in your loop: `disp(outfile);`.  What do you see? Do you see individual file names, or are they concatenating in the behaviour you have in your post above?

Comment: It's still just concatenating the filenames into one long string. Additionally, I'm getting thrown an error about line three: `csv=csvread(files(filenum).name);`

Comment: (1) That could be because the CSV file is invalid.  Check to see if the CSV files in that directory are proper... then again, you're not really using the contents of the CSV file in your code.  (2) Do a `clear all;` then try again.  That shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. The issue was with line 5, `Whole=files(filenum).name`, which I've corrected below:

```
files=dir('all_zrmat/*.csv');
for filenum = 1:length(files)
    csv=csvread(files(filenum).name);
    ROI=[7 8 9 10 28 29 71 72 73 74];
    Whole=csv; % original 116x116 matrix
    rwd_net=ones(10,10);
    rwd_net=rwd_net*3 ; % to make sure all output values are correct 
    for i = 1:10
        rwd_net(i,1:4)=Whole(ROI(i),7:10);
        rwd_net(i,5:6)=Whole(ROI(i),28:29);
        rwd_net(i,7:10)=Whole(ROI(i),71:74);
    end
    outfile=['rwdnet_' files(filenum).name];
    csvwrite(outfile, rwd_net);
end
```

Thanks!